# Seperate CA for etcd in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, etcd, kubernetes-security

I was going through Control Plane Security in Google cloud(GKE) course and referring to 'certificate authority and cluster trust' in the link below and have these questions. Can someone clarify these ?.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/control-plane-security

1. Learnt that every cluster has its on CA that would issue certificates, this part is fine.. there is also a mention on **etcd having seperate CA**...  does it mean a cluster has two CAs, one for rest of the components and one for etcd Or is it just one CA for whole control plane ?
2. It also says, each cluster has its own 'root' CA..I know what CA is, what does *root Certificate Authority* mean ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sorry, I am able to get some info on root CA, which is my second question. Helping with first  question would be fine... thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.- That's correct. There is one certificate for masters and nodes components, and another one for etcd. [This](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust#root_of_trust) article explains is better. Note that it's a GKE approach, not Kubernetes.

2.- The article I passed also explains this second points. Indeed there are two CAs. I quote  "In GKE, the master API certificate is signed by the cluster root CA. Each cluster runs its own CA, so that if one cluster's CA were to be compromised, no other cluster CA would be affected".

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason why GKE do it in this way? Even they use two CAs, both the CA of kubernetes and ETCD are stored in the controlplane. If the hacker has gotten the access to the controlplane, they have gotten the private keys of CAs. It doesn't make any difference to use same CA or seperate CAs.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar questions: The ETCD is hosted in the controlplane. If the hacker can break in the controlplane node, they get everything. Using separate CA for ETCD won't improve the security, so what's the purpose of Seperate CA?

Actually, there are two options for configuring the topology of your highly available (HA) Kubernetes clusters.

1. With stacked control plane nodes, where etcd nodes are colocated with control plane nodes. This approach is so common, that's the reason why many people think of it as the only kubernete infra, but it's wrong.
2. The second approach is external etcd nodes, where etcd runs on separate nodes from the control plane. For this option, the etcd and kubernetes could be managed by two teams. I guess that's the reason why they use separate CA for independent teams.

[image]

### Reference

[kuberenetes Documentation: Options for Highly Available Topology](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/)